How can customise Definition environment to a specific style?
I want to add the definition number inside a blue box, as shown in the image. I've tried several approaches but haven't been successful. Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks

\documentclass[10pt]{book}

% Required packages
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry} % Optional, for better page layout

% Define custom colors
\definecolor{titlecolor}{RGB}{0, 102, 204}

% TikZ triangle for the title
\newcommand{\tikztriangletwo}{\tikz\draw[fill=white,draw=white] (0,0) -- (0.2,0.1) -- (0,0.2) -- cycle;\hspace{3pt}}

% Define a tcolorbox environment for the theorem with blue background for the title only
\tcolorboxenvironment{definition}{
  breakable,
  boxrule=0pt,
  boxsep=2pt,
  before skip=10pt,
  after skip=10pt,
  colframe=white,
  sharp corners,
  colback=white, % White background for the content
  colbacktitle=titlecolor, % Blue background for the title
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\setstretch{0.5},
  title={\tikztriangletwo Definition} % Ensure proper spacing in title
}

% Custom theorem style
\newtheoremstyle{definitionstyle}%
  {}% Space above
  {}% Space below
  {}% Body font
  {}% Indent amount
  {\sffamily}% The body font
  {}% Punctuation after theorem head
  {}% Space after theorem head
  {}% Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{definitionstyle}
\newtheorem*{definition}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}

\begin{definition}
    Hi I am definition 1.1
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
    Hi I am definition 1.2
\end{definition}

\end{document}


You could use \NewTcbTheorem to create new theorems with tcolorboxes:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

% Required packages
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry} % Optional, for better page layout

% Define custom colors
\definecolor{titlecolor}{RGB}{0, 102, 204}

% TikZ triangle for the title
\newcommand{\tikztriangletwo}{\tikz\draw[fill=white,draw=white] (0,0) -- (0.2,0.1) -- (0,0.2) -- cycle;\hspace{3pt}}

% Define a tcolorbox environment for the theorem with blue background for the title only
\NewTcbTheorem[number within=chapter]{definition}{\tikztriangletwo\ Definition} {
  breakable,
  boxrule=0pt,
  boxsep=2pt,
  before skip=10pt,
  after skip=10pt,
  colframe=white,
  sharp corners,
  colback=white, % White background for the content
  colbacktitle=titlecolor, % Blue background for the title
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\setstretch{0.5},
}{def}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}

\begin{definition}{}{labela}
    Hi I am definition \ref{def:labela}
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}{Some name}{labelb}
    Hi I am definition \ref{def:labelb}
\end{definition}

\end{document}


